# Creating a form with will fill up checkout and cart details on woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, forms, woocommerce, payment, checkout

i would like to create a form in which after a client fills in the form and mentions how many units of a product (for example soft toys) he would like, then we could proceed into checkout where he can make the payment.

its basically going to be a random selection page, given that all toys are the same price. If someone goes into the page and fills the form he can select how many he wants and put in his or her details then we will proceed to payment.

I am using wordpress and woocommerce.

Comment: 1st of all the information is not enough and please post what code you have tried

Comment: i have tried to create a form using contact form 7 but could not link it to woocommerce as i couldnt find appropriate details on it.

Comment: If he is a logged in user .. then name and other details then it will be filled up automatically. Now with that form and quantity you need items in cart. use the following code for that -

global $woocommerce;
$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($product_id);

Now if you need to pre populate the checkout fields you can check this article - http://www.mingocommerce.com/pre-populate-woocommerce-checkout-fields/

Comment: thanks for that, but i also need the quantity to change on the cart automatically as i want to charge my clients as soon as they select "auto select your toys"

Comment: I think, woocommerce default functionality will do that